# Java array records

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, records

I need to get an variable type that has 3 types of values, the only way I know to do that is "Records", but I know there is no such type as "Records" in Java but `ArrayList`, but I don't get it...

My result should be: (Don't know how it would look in Java, so I'm showing in different style)

```
TData = Record
     Username : String;
     UserID : Int ;
     RowID : Int;
   end;
users : array[1..10] of TData;

for(int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++){
   TData.Username[i] = rs.GetString("Name");
   TData.UserID[i] = rs.GetInt("UserID");
   TData.RowID[i] = row;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make something like this?
Is `ArrayList` that I really need?

Thanks for the help, at the end i combined and got this result, works perfectly:

```
class MyData {
        private String userName;
        private int userID;
        private int RowID;


        public MyData(String userName, int userID, int RowID) {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.userID = userID;
            this.RowID = RowID;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public int getUserID() {
            return userID;
        }
        public int getRowID() {
            return RowID;
        }
    }

    public void AList(){
        ArrayList<MyData> users = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            conn = DBConnection.DBConnector();
            pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TableUserData");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            row = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                users.add(new MyData(rs.getString("User_name"), rs.getInt("ID"), row));
                row++;
                }
            for (MyData tmp : users) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Users: " + tmp.getUserName() + " row: " + rtmp.getRowID());

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arraylist error: " + e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You could make your own `Record` class and give it those fields.

Comment: Instead of records, you use classes in Java. Java has arrays, which are same as in Pascal. ArrayList is a List, which using Array for storing items, it is not array itself (however it is usually better to use, because you dont have to set the size of it, it is resizing automatically)

Comment: @glglgl OP has said that *don't know how it would look in java so, i'm showing in different style* How can you change his *pseudo-code* to yours? And certainly there are more important things to edit.

Comment: @johnchen902 This pseudo code is clearly inspired by Pascal, and even it it wouldn't, there would be no point to access fields of the type, so I changed that, taking care that I don't change the intention of all. If you see other things worth to be changed, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing up things.

An `ArrayList` is a flexible alternative to an array and serves to store "a bunch" of data which have the same type.

The type of these data (of one entry) is up to you.

The standard way of doing this in Java is to define a class like

```
class MyData {
    private String userName;
    private int userID;
    private int rowID;

    public MyData(String userName, int userID, int rowID) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.rowID = rowID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public int getRowID() {
        return rowID;
    }
}
```

and then

```
ArrayList<MyData> users = new ArrayList<>();

while (rs.next()) {
   users.add(new MyData(rs.GetString("Name"), rs.GetInt("UserID"), rs.GetInt("RowID")));
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add the arguments to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code snippet -

```
int salary;
float bonus;
char YesOrNo = 'Y';
```

Here `salary`, `bonus` and `YesOrNo` all of these are data and `int`, `float` and `char` are data type. We called `salary` is an `int` type data, `bonus` is a `float` type data. Here `int`, `float`, `char` - these data type are of primitive type in `java`.

In addition to primitive type you can create your own data type in `object oriented` programming language like - `java`. Here I think you can create a class of named `Record` or with some other more meaningful name -

```
public class Record {
    private String userName;
    private int userId; 
    private int rowId;

    public Record(String userName, int userId, int rowId){
      this.userName = userName;
      this.userId = userId;
      this.rowId
    }

    //getter and setter methods  if required
}
```

After that when you create a instance/object of `Record`  -

```
Record aRecord = new Record("user001", 1, 1);
```

Then in `OOP`  we called the newly created class - `Record` as a user defined data type. Now we can called `aRecord` as a `Record` type data.

Then you can use `ArrayList` to store the `Record` type data -

```
List<Record> recordList = new ArrayList<Recored>();
```